# How to create a column/bar chart with time interval that's not based on hours?

Tags: charts, google-visualization, bar-chart, data-visualization

[image]

The graph visualizes the following `timeofday` and `number` schema data

```
[[4, 0, 0], 1600, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[[4, 13, 0], 0, 400, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[[4, 14, 0], 1600, 400, 0, 0, 0, 0],
```

What I want to achieve is have blue bar span across from 4:00 to 4:14 and red bar span from 4:13 to 4:14.

Any idea how this could be achieved?

Comment: Look into the variableWidth option.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Turns out I was just using a wrong chart. I used a stepped area chart instead. Even though the document says it only takes in string, you can pass in time of the day to create it.